# How can I fix the contrast of the GNOME desktop on a Macbook Pro 2011

Tags: graphics, macbook, color-depth

I am using Ubuntu 22.10 on my Macbook Pro (late 2011, NOT retina).
Does anybody else use this machine?

I think that the white balance (or contrast or whatever) is very bad. Some UI elements are very difficult to differentiate because of this...

How could I fix it?

Comment: This question would likely get more traffic if the question was stated in the title (perhaps like "How can I fix the contrast of the GNOME desktop on a MBP 2011?")

Comment: Thanks for your time and input! I changed my question and hopefully, I will get some answers :)